# listen to deeply nested react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am currently working on a music player in React.
So far I have a Context Provider with a music element stored with the `useState` hook.

```
const [currentSong, setCurrentSong] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    fetchSong();
}, []);

const fetchSong = () => {
    const songAudio = new Audio(`localhost/song/13/audio`)
    songAudio.onloadeddata = () => {
    songAudio.play();
    setCurrentSong(songAudio);
    }
}
```

After that the currentSong Object looks something like this

```
<audio preload="auto" src="http://localhost/song/13/audio">
{...}
duration: 239.081
currentTime: 113.053
​{...}
<prototype>: HTMLAudioElementPrototype { … }
```

Because the song is playing the currentTime gets updated automatically.

My question is if it is possible to trigger a rerender every time `currentTime` changes so that I can update a span element with that number.
The span is in a seperate file and consumes the Context Provider which provides the `currentSong` object.

```
const { currentSong, {...} } = useMusicContext();

{...}

return (
<span className='...'>
  {currentSong? currentSong.currentTime: "0:00"}
</span>
)
```

The problem is that the component does not know that the `currentTime` value changed and only updates the text if a rerender is triggered by something else.

Comment: You can use the nested property as a dependency for a React hook. Can you edit the post to include a more complete [mcve] so we can see what the code is doing and how the state is updated and for what you are trying to do?

Comment: How is the `currentTime` property updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event listener to the audio element for [timeupdate events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event) and use those to update your state (or whatever).

Here's a [quick demo implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/audio-time-update-demo-mn0tyk). Source included below for easier reference.

```
// Audio component to handle attaching the listener
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export function Audio({ onTimeUpdate, ...props }) {
  const audioRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const { current } = audioRef;
    current?.addEventListener("timeupdate", onTimeUpdate);

    return () => current?.removeEventListener("timeupdate", onTimeUpdate);
  }, [audioRef, onTimeUpdate]);

  return (
    <audio ref={audioRef} {...props} />
  );
}
```

```
export default function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState();

  const onTimeUpdate = (e) => {
    setTime(e.target.currentTime);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Audio onTimeUpdate={onTimeUpdate} controls src="./audio-sample.mp3" />
      <div>{time}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Tough to exactly say what to do here - would need more info/code, but I do believe that passing down `currentTime` as a prop would work.

If that is not possible, or you don't want to keep passing down props, you may want to look into the react hook called `useContext`.

Alternatively, perhaps you could use `useEffect` to trigger re-renders in the component you want to update. Not exactly sure how you would trigger this re-render/what you would put in the dependency array without more info.